# React native facebook login recevied user name pass to set profile screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, facebook-login, expo

I'm using react native with expo and I received user name via facebook login code is here :

```
export default class FacebookLogin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userInfo: null };
  }
  _handleFacebookLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
        'my own app is not a problem',
        { permissions: ['public_profile'] }
      );

  switch (type) {
    case 'success': {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`
      );
      const userInfo = await response.json();
      this.setState({ userInfo });
      Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${userInfo.name}`);
      this.props.facebookloginpress();
      break;
    }
    case 'cancel': {
      Alert.alert('Cancelled!', 'Login was cancelled!');
      break;
    }
    default: {
      Alert.alert('Oops!', 'Login failed!');
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  Alert.alert('Oops!', 'Login failed!');
}
  };
 render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button
              title="Login with Facebook"
              onPress={this._handleFacebookLogin}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

it is okay not a problem but I want to pass userInfo.name to my Profile screen and to print as a text on my profile screen, profil screen code is here:

```
export default class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  handleSignOutPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginScreen');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
        <Text>This text take a facebook username</Text>
        <Button
          backgroundColor="#03A9F4"
          title="SIGN OUT"
          onPress={this.handleSignOutPress}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

// thanks for your help

Comment: what is the problem with that? looks like a basic react issue, you can use props to send the user name to the profile, or (better) use redux.

Comment: I tried that but state is change after to user facebook logins and I m don't pass to facebook username to profile screen and when I use the props, profile screen component seen the facebook login screen I'm don't want this